# Helper method to log in in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, minitest

Just wondering what the best way to setup something in Minitest acceptance tests to log in before a test.

I'm switching from Cucumber, where it would usually be something like this:

step("log in as userx")

Would I simply define a method to utilise Capybara in my minitest_helper.rb or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't testing the login functionality you should be able to create an object of your `User` class and log it in (set a session).

If you want to you can put that into your `minitest_helper.rb` so you have a blank slate everytime you need a logged in user.